# Handling Runtime exceptions in transactional jdbc code

Tags: exception, jdbc, transactions

A coworker and I are having a disagreement on the best practice for handling run-time exceptions thrown from transactional JDBC code. He feels that catching `Exception` rather than `SQLException` is the proper practice.

His argument is that `Connection.close();` has an undefined behaviour if the transaction has not been committed. Some JDBC implementations may do a rollback, while others may do a commit. If you just catch the `SQLException`, then any runtime exception will have undefined behaviour on the `close()` in the `finally` block.

Is it currently considered best practice to catch `Exception`, and if not, how do you address the situation he describes?

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = ...
    // transactional code
} catch (final Exception e) {
    connection.rollback();
} finally {
    // close other resources
    if (connection != null) { connection.close(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would catch Exception too and even Throwable.  It all depends on the code inside your block.

Ex:

If you call another DAO to persist another entity, you will for sure catch any kind of exception to make sure you rollback your trx.

You have to ask this question to yourself : do i want to commit the trx even if some non SQLException occur?

From my experience, my answer would be No! ;-)

But that's just me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As per Javadoc of java.sql.Connection, behaviour of close is implementation dependent.

It is **strongly recommended** that an application explicitly 
commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the 
`close` method.  If the `close` method is called
 and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined.

Its safe to catch and take decision to commit / rollback on basis of business requirement